Why is Baker's Yeast not chametz gamur?
The OU Pesach Guide says Brewer's Yeast is chametz gamur but that Bakers Yeast is not.
Why is Bakers Yeast not chametz gamur. Is it not שְׂאֹ֖ר?
Or is OU saying that chametz gamur is not the same as שְׂאֹ֖ר?

Se'or is sourdough. Baker's yeast is just a fungus, not a grain product. It is not chametz at all. If you mix it with flour and water, however, chametz will result

OU website explains

The se’or prohibited by the Torah does not refer to baker’s yeast.
Se’or is sourdough, which is made by allowing raw dough to become
moldy and capable of leavening future dough. Baker’s yeast, however,
is a microorganism propagated on various media, typically, in its
final production stage, on molasses. It can be sold before Pesach even
by people who are careful to avoid selling chametz gamor. Baker’s
yeast should not, however, be consumed on Pesach. Even if a
manufacturer claims that the medium for producing yeast is molasses,
it should not be used. The production process for yeast involves
multiple stages, and it is possible that the manufacturer is referring
only to the final production stage.


I looked up both on the web.  It seems nowadays the two terms are used synonymously, for example:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18335702/
